# Accessing a song loaded with AVPlayer

Tags: objective-c, save, nsdata, avplayer

I want to save a song that I loaded with method - (id)initWithURL: of AVPlayer, so I don't need to load it next time I want to play it. I've spent hours browsing Apple documentation, but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a URL, you can simply use either `NSURLConnection` or similar classes to download the URL to local storage. `AVPlayer` won't do this for you, though - you'll have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

As @iKenndac said, you can't get this out of AVPlayer. You can download the file yourself and store it to disk but you will lose out on all the optimizations that AVPlayer offers in terms of downloading a song and starting to play it as fast as possible. Certainly the next time you play the song you will reap the benefits of having the song on disk already. If that trade off is fine with you then in your NSURLConnection callbacks will do something like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:someFilePath];
    [myHandle writeData:responseData];
    [myHandle synchronizeFile];
    [myHandle closeFile];           
}
```

You will have to define responseData as an NSMutableData object and be sure to initialize it before calling appendData.